# Math at the end of case statements is ignoring the case statements SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

```sql
SELECT
    A.a_id,
    A.a_q1,
    CASE
    WHEN A.a_q2 = 5 then 1
    WHEN A.a_q2 = 4 then 2
    WHEN A.a_q2 = 3 then 3
    WHEN A.a_q2 = 2 then 4
    WHEN A.a_q2 = 1 then 5
    else A.a_q2 end as a_q2, a_q3,
    CASE
    WHEN A.a_q4 = 5 then 1
    WHEN A.a_q4 = 4 then 2
    WHEN A.a_q4 = 3 then 3
    WHEN A.a_q4 = 2 then 4
    WHEN A.a_q4 = 1 then 5
    else A.a_q4 end as a_q4, a_q5,
   (a_q1 + a_q3 + a_q4 + a_q5)/4 AS         "construct_1",
   (a_q1 + a_q2 + a_q3 + a_q4)/4 AS         "construct_2"
    FROM ANSWERS A
```

My output:

| a_id | construct_1 | construct_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5000 | 3.5000 |
| 2 | 4.0000 | 3.2500 |
| 3 | 2.0000 | 2.7500 |
| 4 | 2.5000 | 3.5000 |
| 5 | 2.0000 | 2.7500 |
| 6 | 4.0000 | 3.2500 |

Expected output:

| a_id | construct_1 | construct_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.5000 | 3.50000 |
| 2 | 3.0000 | 3.25000 |
| 3 | 3.5000 | 2.7500 |
| 4 | 1.5000 | 1.5000 |
| 5 | 3.0000 | 3.2500 |
| 6 | 4.0000 | 3.7500 |

Data set:

| a_id | q_1 | q_2 | q_3 | q_4 | q_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 5 |

I'm new to SQL and having trouble with creating a column from the case statements. The math at the end is not doing calculation with any of the updated numbers in the case statement.

Comment: Please simplify your query to be as small as possible required to demonstrate the problem and show sample data and actual vs expected output - see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, I hope you don’t expect columns in the calculation to be the results of the case statements.

Comment: Edited to keep it as little as possible

Comment: Please don't link to images of data in your question. Add the data as editable text so that all the information is visible in one place and people can copy the data if they want to try out a possible answer. Also please add sample data and the result you expect to see based on that sample data

Comment: Edited again, thank you guys for being patient with me and teaching me the correct etiquette.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  However, column aliases defined in a `select` cannot be used in the same select for operations.  So the references are to the original values in the columns.

Comment: I'm using MariaDB, how would I go about it? Do I do a nested Select?

Comment: Soo.. why don't you just do `6 - whatever` to turn a `whatever` of 5/4/3/2/1 into 1/2/3/4/5 respectively?

Comment: @CaiusJard because for values outside 1-5 that formula doesn’t apply, although you could simplify to `case when x between 1 and 5 then 6 - x else x end`

Comment: @Bohemian iindeed, that's exactly what I just said. Nowhere did I state *`6-x` is a replacement for the entire case statement* - I simply said that the conversion of 5->1, 4->2 etc can be achieved with 6-x (and I proposed a case similar to your suggestion in the answer below)

Answer (score 0):

> The math at the end is not doing calculation with any of the updated numbers in the case statement.

SQL doesn't work like that. Everything in the `SELECT` list is an independent statement that is applied to the data coming out of the `FROM[/WHERE[/GROUP]]`. It is not a "top to bottom list of executed code that modifies itself line by line" like a programming language

```
SELECT
  name,
  CONCAT(name, 'hello') as name,
  name
FROM
  person
```

Will produce:

```
Name Name      Name
John Johnhello John
```

The middle `CONCAT(name, 'hello') as name` does not redefine some variable called `name`/has no influence on any of the other uses of `name` anywhere else in the select

If you want `a_q4` in this:

```
(a_q1 + a_q3 + a_q4 + a_q5)/4 AS         "construct_1",
```

To behave like this:

```
CASE
WHEN A.a_q4 = 5 then 1
WHEN A.a_q4 = 4 then 2
WHEN A.a_q4 = 3 then 3
WHEN A.a_q4 = 2 then 4
WHEN A.a_q4 = 1 then 5
else A.a_q4 end
```

Then you have to put all that into the calc

```
(a_q1 + a_q3 + 

CASE
WHEN A.a_q4 = 5 then 1
WHEN A.a_q4 = 4 then 2
WHEN A.a_q4 = 3 then 3
WHEN A.a_q4 = 2 then 4
WHEN A.a_q4 = 1 then 5
else A.a_q4 end

+ a_q5)/4 AS         "construct_1",
```

---

Or you use a subquery (or CTE) to redefine what `a_q4` means. To be honest you'd be better off using different names so you don't confuse yourself:

```
SELECT 
  (a_q1 + a_q3 + adjusted_a_q4 + a_q5)/4 AS         "construct_1", --use the different name
  ...
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ...
    CASE
      WHEN A.a_q4 = 5 then 1
      WHEN A.a_q4 = 4 then 2
      WHEN A.a_q4 = 3 then 3
      WHEN A.a_q4 = 2 then 4
      WHEN A.a_q4 = 1 then 5
    else A.a_q4 end as adjusted_a_q4, --alias it using a different name
    ... 
  FROM ANSWERS A
) x
```

---

ps; your case when block is effectively the same as `CASE WHEN A.a_q4 BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN 6 - a.a_q4 ELSE a_q4 END`, and if there isn't going to be an else, just do `6-a_q4` (which will let you neatly skip the subquery as it can be just inserted into the original calcs)